# MQTT over Secure Websockets Socket Closed After a Minute - RabbitMQ

Tags: angular, websocket, rabbitmq, mqtt, paho

I'm connecting to an MQTT RabbitMQ instance over Secure Websockets (Angular 6 using this module, `import { Paho } from 'ng2-mqtt/mqttws31'`). It connects successfully but the socket connection seems to close after a minute. It doesn't matter what the KeepAliveInterval is set to, it always seems to close the socket connection after a minute.

This is my client connection:

`this.client.connect({ userName: "username", password: "password", onSuccess: this.onConnect.bind(this), useSSL: true, timeout: 60, keepAliveInterval: 6000 });`

I am not sure if the problem is on the RabbitMQ server or on the Angular side. Any help will be deeply appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried setting the keepAliveInterval to less than 60 seconds? Reading the Paho code suggests that it sends the server a ping at 'keepAliveInterval' seconds, so maybe the server is closing the connection after 60 seconds of inactivity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try setting your keepAliveInterval to, say, 30.

I suspect that your MQTT server has a default keepalive set to 60 seconds, which means that it is likely to close the connection soon after 60 seconds if it has not had any communication with the client within this time. The keepAliveInterval field that you set should be at most as large as the keepalive of the server, because that determines how frequently the client will ping the server in the advent of a quiet connection.

[Here](http://docs.oasis-open.org/mqtt/mqtt/v5.0/cs02/mqtt-v5.0-cs02.html#_Toc514345317) is KeepAlive defined in the MQTT spec.

Comment: Perfect! I owe you a chocolate!!! I've been scratching my head around this for 2 days. Just to help me, can you direct me to where I can find the part you mentioned, "Reading the Paho code suggests that it sends the server a ping at 'keepAliveInterval' seconds"

Comment: Sure - see here from around line 700 - 740. https://github.com/eclipse/paho.mqtt.javascript/blob/9b761defeeb4a627db31d92ae1b0ca91b44b226e/src/paho-mqtt.js

Comment: Incidentally, the spec for MQTT says that when the server sends back confirmation after setting up a connection with the client, it can tell the client what the keepAliveInterval should be, and the client MUST use this value instead of what it originally specified. Paho in JS doesn't do this.... _daydreams about pull requests_

Comment: How can I increase the keepalive for my rabbitMQ-mqtt server?