# MQTT over WS keep closing connection after several minutes

Tags: javascript, rabbitmq, mqtt

I am using this [MQTT library](https://github.com/mqttjs/MQTT.js) and I am having a problem with the stability of the WS connection with RabbitMQ server. I was having the same issue as in this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55119474/mqtt-over-secure-websockets-socket-closed-after-a-minute-rabbitmq) so I tried to modify the keepalive parameter and I set it to value between 10 ~ 30. Unfortunately, it only postponed the time of the first connection lost. As we can see from the following logs, the MQTT library is sending ping requests with pong responses until the time 11:03:03 then it stops so the RabbitMQ server close the connection at 10:03:27 with keepalive timeout. After this, the connection is closed every minute. Does anybody have an idea why the client stops to send a ping requests ? Is there any other parameter to set or it is a bug of the library ?

WebSocket log of my MQTT application:

[image]

RabbitMQ log:

```
2021-11-22 09:47:27.468546+00:00 [info] <0.4623.0> accepting Web MQTT connection <0.4623.0> (172.17.0.1:55698 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:03:27.696946+00:00 [erro] <0.4623.0> closing Web MQTT connection "172.17.0.1:55698 -> 172.17.0.2:15675" (keepalive timeout)
2021-11-22 10:03:27.697218+00:00 [info] <0.4623.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.4623.0> (172.17.0.1:55698 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:03:27.698273+00:00 [info] <0.4623.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.4623.0> (172.17.0.1:55698 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:03:29.182969+00:00 [info] <0.14753.0> accepting Web MQTT connection <0.14753.0> (172.17.0.1:55764 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:04:29.204717+00:00 [erro] <0.14753.0> closing Web MQTT connection "172.17.0.1:55764 -> 172.17.0.2:15675" (keepalive timeout)
2021-11-22 10:04:29.204870+00:00 [info] <0.14753.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.14753.0> (172.17.0.1:55764 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:04:29.205730+00:00 [info] <0.14753.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.14753.0> (172.17.0.1:55764 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:04:31.183652+00:00 [info] <0.15421.0> accepting Web MQTT connection <0.15421.0> (172.17.0.1:55770 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:05:31.200648+00:00 [erro] <0.15421.0> closing Web MQTT connection "172.17.0.1:55770 -> 172.17.0.2:15675" (keepalive timeout)
2021-11-22 10:05:31.200764+00:00 [info] <0.15421.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.15421.0> (172.17.0.1:55770 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
2021-11-22 10:05:31.201699+00:00 [info] <0.15421.0> closing Web MQTT connection <0.15421.0> (172.17.0.1:55770 -> 172.17.0.2:15675)
```

To reproduce the issue you can use this [repository](https://github.com/horak90/mqtt_ws_connection).

The problem seems to be only for the browser implementation, once the application is launched in node.js the connection is not dropping.

Thanks for any help

Comment: We probably need some more context here. Where is the client code running? Is it a NodeJS app or in a browser? Is there a proxy server between the client and the broker?

Comment: I did the tests locally on my machine so the application was running in a browser and there is no proxy server between the rabbitMQ (running in docker) and my application.

Comment: Edit the question to include the minimal viable testcase that shows the problem.

Comment: I updated the question with the repository which shows the problem and I also observe that the problem occurs only for browser. Thanks for any help

Comment: I have the same problem with VerneMQ. MQTT.js does not keep the WS open, but closes the connection immediately after each publish/subscribe